# Laravel 5.3 Notifications Seeder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-seeding

What I am trying to acheive - is create a database seeder for Laravel Notifications. As far as i am using database to store my notifications, there should be a way to achieve it. I am creating Factory model :

```
$user->notify(new NotificationEvent($event));
```

In fact it creates a notification in database, but artisan returns with error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                   
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::save()
```

Anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a namespace issue, please try the following, place the class reference on top of your seed class:

```
use Notification;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me!